# what is the differences in the different pre-build spark edition

Tags: apache-spark

I don't know the differences in the different pre-built edition spark.such as,pre-built for 2.4 hadoop and later and for 2.3 hadoop.  this difference tell us 
whether the spark edition need the designated kind of hadoop edition，such as 2.4 and 2.3 .
 sorry,my english is poor.if don't understand my question,wish you tell me.
 think you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think pre-build apache spark distribution for Hadoop 2.4 and later using own hadoop hdfs file system.This file system is in that file.But another choices doesn't have hadoop file system this will use use hadoop file system but already it is in your computer. I hope use understand and if you will use for testing you should install pre-build.
Have a nice days :)

Comment: Thank you,I still have a little question.your means that if I use the pre-build apache spark 2.4 and late,I don't need install hadoop file system in my computer.Is right?

Comment: yes, i have hadoop and spark but my spark don't using hadoop file system in my computer.

Comment: sorry,i want to  more about  how to use the  pre-build apache spark 2.4 and later' hdfs . what i should  do if i want to read file from own  hdfs or where  this found  in spark documents.thank you !